# add date to every name

Tags: mysql, sql

hello please help me to solve this,, i am using *mysql*.. and I think, needing a **full outer join** to solve it,.
this is my query:

```
SELECT
  e.NIK,
  e.name,
  a.dt
FROM
  employee e
    LEFT JOIN
  attandence a
    ON e.NIK=a.NIK
WHERE
  month(a.dt)=12 AND year(a.dt)=2021
GROUP BY
  e.NIK
```

this is the result:

| NIK | name | dt |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | ana | 23/12/2021 |
| 001 | ana | 24/12/2021 |
| 001 | ana | 26/12/2021 |
| 001 | ana | 27/12/2021 |
| 002 | susi | 23/12/2021 |
| 002 | susi | 24/12/2021 |
| 002 | susi | 25/12/2021 |
| 002 | susi | 26/12/2021 |

but i need to join it one more time with this table :
**holidayTable**

| id | mark | dt |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | off_day | 22/12/2021 |
| 2 | chrismast | 25/12/2021 |

- I've tried using left/right/cross join, but it doesn't work

The result I want is like this:

| NIK | name | dtWork | holiday |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | ana | *null* | 22/12/2021 |
| 001 | ana | 23/12/2021 | *null* |
| 001 | ana | 24/12/2021 | *null* |
| 001 | ana | *null* | 25/12/2021 |
| 001 | ana | 26/12/2021 | *null* |
| 001 | ana | 27/12/2021 | *null* |
| 002 | susi | *null* | 22/12/2021 |
| 002 | susi | 23/12/2021 | *null* |
| 002 | susi | 24/12/2021 | *null* |
| 002 | susi | 25/12/2021 | 25/12/2021 |
| 002 | susi | 26/12/2021 | *null* |

Comment: Kindly add the other table in your example.

Comment: You didn't say what you are trying to achieve, and your query has problems in that you are grouping without aggregation so it's difficult to guess intent. I guess you are attempting to get work and holiday days for every worker in december 2021

Comment: @P.Salmon 
yes you're right. I mean I want to take working days and days off for every worker

Comment: @the_coding_cat what other tables?

Comment: @rejaeja you said you are JOINING two tables but you only provide the holidaytable in the example.

Answer (score 1):

You need a calendar table to achieve the output.
As of now I used union between `holidaytable` and `attendance` as Calendar.

You can achieve your desired result with below query.

```
SELECT e.nik,
       e.name,
       a.dt AS dtWork,
       h.dt AS holiday
FROM   employee e
       CROSS JOIN(SELECT dt
                  FROM   holidaytable
                  UNION
                  SELECT dt
                  FROM   attendance)cal
                 LEFT JOIN attendance a
                        ON e.nik = a.nik
                           AND a.dt = cal.dt
                 LEFT JOIN holidaytable h
                        ON h.dt = cal.dt
WHERE  a.dt IS NOT NULL
        OR h.dt IS NOT NULL
ORDER  BY nik ASC,
          cal.dt ASC
```

SQLFiddle: [Try it here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7b05aa3/1)

Answer (score 0):

A union where the first part gets attendence and the second gets holidays (with as you thought a cross join) including a dummy column to assist ordering

```
select e.id,employeelastname,a.dt attendence,null holiday,a.dt as orderdt
from   employees e
left   join attendence a on a.nik = e.id 
union
select e.id,employeelastname,null,h.dt holiday,h.dt
from   employees e
cross  join   holidays h
order by id,orderdt;
```

Comment: This will not handle the scenario where date is present in both `attendance` and `holiday` table. Example: 25/12/2021 for employee `susi`, your query will give two different rows.